# Kineticjs: what's the difference between .get and .find methods?

Tags: kineticjs

As stated in the title,what's difference between

```
stage.get("#id")
```

and

```
stage.find("#id")
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same.

.get has been deprecated in favor of .find, so I suspect .get will be removed in some future version.